# How many possible square matrices can be formed with n number of elements in a set/array?

Tags: matrices

if I had a set like $[1,2,3,4,\cdots,n]$ where $n$ is even ($n$ is divisible by 2). How many possible square matrices can be formed? What would the algorithm for the same would be?

Note: I am just starting out in this community. I'd posted this question before but was not well received. If there's anything obtuse about this question, let me know in the comments and I'll remove this question.

Comment: Could the square matrix have any size? Is it limited to $\sqrt n\times \sqrt n$? Can a number be used more than once? Is there any reason to care about the fact that these are matrices, or could the question just as well be "how many ways are there to pick out a sequence whose length is a square number?"

Comment: Suppose you have a $2\times 2$ matrice. Then you have for every of the $2\cdot 2=4$ values in the matrice n possiblilities. Making a total number of $4^n$ possible $2\times 2$ matrices.

Comment: i'm sorry guys I just realized that my question is flawed. there would always be only one possibility for a square matrix to be formed from a set of, let's say, 16 elements..... so how many matrices can be made of those 16 elements of any dimension....??

Comment: I think I'm close to the answer, does anyone know how to sum a geometric series whose ratio is in geometric series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number of Possible $1\times1$ Matrix = $n$

Number of possible $2\times2$ matrix = $n^4$

Number of possible $m\times m$ matrix = $n^{m^2}$

Total number of square matrix till m = $n+n^4+n^9+.....+n^{m^2}$ [If someone can sum this please do tell me]

Now, finding $m^2$

$m^2$ is obviously the largest square number smaller than number of elemnts in set (Here, $n$)

Thus, $m^2=\lfloor \sqrt n\rfloor^2$

That is, say if n = 24, $\sqrt n=4.9,\lfloor \sqrt n\rfloor=4$ and hence $m = 4$

Comment: however, i need simplified version of `m =  n+n4+n9+.....+nm2`

Comment: but, thanks anyway. that was somewhat what i needed